# Is it a Bad idea to use `<%=` in a WebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, declarative

Recently I've started using `<%=` more often in my Web Controls. Typically I'll set String properties in the Code Behind and then spit them out onto the form.

Is this a bad idea?

eg.

Code Behind:

Properties:

```
public string TheTitle { get; set; }
public string TheBody { get; set; }
public ContentItem TheContent { get; set; }
public string ContentId { 
  get 
    { return "content" + (TheContent != null) ? TheContent.Id.ToSTring() : "0"; }
}
```

Page_Load:

```
TheTitle = TheContentItem.Title;
TheBody = TheContentItem.Body;
```

On Page:

```
<div id='<%= ContentID %>'>    

  <h2 class='title'><%= TheTitle ?? "No Title" %></h2>
  <p><%= TheBody %></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think it might be a bad idea?

Comment: If you're going to all the trouble of have ViewModel type properties in your CodeBehind, why don't you move to MVC?

Comment: Actually, I am moving to MVC for new projects. But I'm not going to rewrite old ones.

Comment: @Robaticus. I guess it just seems that for WebForms, it seemed... somehow wrong. I'm taking this approach as I've been doing a lot of MVC recently. I figured since I was using the Literal Control quite a bit in my webforms, that there isn't much difference between just outputting it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only a problem when the data is not validated.

Using .NET 4's `<%: TheBody %>` syntax is an effective way to encode potentially-untrusted data. In earlier versions of the framework, you can use `<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TheBody) %>` to the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad if the data comes from an user input as your site will be vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a problem* because it will be scoped to your control.  You don't have to worry about anything conflicting in your case but if you were writing out server controls with IDs you could run into problems.

How your using it, ok (*assuming you have cleaned the data before assigning it to your variable).  Just keep in mind there are times when it can be an issue with duplication of IDs, controls, scripts, etc...

**Edit:** Before assigning it to your varible you could use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` or if you using ASP.NET 4 you can use the `<%:` syntax depending on what you are outputting.  This fall under the same rules as doing it an aspx, it's ok but you just need to be careful.  This is also how much of ASP.NET MVC is used.  The views can be literred with `<%=` and `<%:` Obviously using any type of encoding on any HTML itself would not be useful.